# How does tail recursion change big O?

Tags: scheme, time-complexity, big-o, racket, tail-recursion

Not tail optimised:

```
(define (my-length lst)
  (cond
   [(empty? lst) 0]
   [else (+ 1 (my-length (rest lst)))]))
```

Result:

```
(my-length (list "a" "b" "c"))
= (+ 1 (my-length (list "b" "c")))
= (+ 1 (+ 1 (my-length (list "c"))))
= (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (my-length (list)))))
= (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 0)))
= (+ 1 (+ 1 1))
= (+ 1 2)
= 3
```

Tail optimized:

```
(define (my-length lst)
  ; local function iter:
  (define (iter lst len)
    (cond
     [(empty? lst) len]
     [else (iter (rest lst) (+ len 1))]))
  ; body of my-length calls iter:
  (iter lst 0))
```

Result:

```
(my-length (list "a" "b" "c"))
= (iter (list "a" "b" "c") 0)
= (iter (list "b" "c") 1)
= (iter (list "c") 2)
= (iter (list) 3)
3
```

How has big-O improved? [Racket's docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Lists__Iteration__and_Recursion.html#%28part._tail-recursion%29) say the first is O(n) but the second is run in constant space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Tail recursive implementations aren't guaranteed to save *time*, instead they guarantee saving *space* - the stack will not grow

Also note, Racket has [named let](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29) which allows you to write the tail recursive form a bit nicer

```
(define (length xs)
  (let loop ((xs xs) (len 0))
    (if (empty? xs)
        len
        (loop (cdr xs) (+ 1 len)))))
```

Racket also supports pattern matching via [match](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html)

```
(define (length xs)
  (let loop ((xs xs) (len 0))
    (match xs
      ((cons _ rest) (loop rest (+ 1 len)))
      (empty len))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I get it now. It's about space (RAM) complexity not about time complexity.